# Shopify REST API: Paid+Fulfilled and fully Refunded orders not retrievable by filter (but can be by ID)

Tags: shopify-api

The requirement is to periodically download all newly fulfilled or refunded orders from Shopify using the REST API. This has been attempted using parameters for modified date and status. This is the endpoint, and [documentation is here](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/3800273/SWLk55pF#9615f84f-dd1c-43b7-92ec-a113ea2397d7).

/admin/api/{{api_version}}/orders.json

However, orders which are in either of the following states seem to always be excluded from the results:

- Payment Status=Paid & FulfillmentStatus=Fulfilled
- Payment Status=Refunded

In the Shopify admin UI, these appear greyed out in the order list.

I don't think these orders have become archived because even very recent (today's) orders are excluded, and also they can be retrieved by order ID using this endpoint:

/admin/api/{{api_version}}/orders/{{order_id}}.json

Is there any way to incrementally query for orders in these states, i.e. without knowing the IDs?

How the inaccessible orders appear in the UI:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer: orders in the above 2 states have an overall status of "closed" (as opposed to "open" or "cancelled"). Closed orders appear greyed out in the UI.

When querying for orders via the List endpoint, you can specify a status parameter, but if you do not Shopify applies a default of "open", so closed orders are excluded. Specify status="closed" to access closed orders only, or status="any" to access all statuses.